# Indy10, IdTCPClient's IOHandler send additional data

Tags: indy10

Trying to send a data to another machine. I use C++Builder XE6 and Indy10.

```
TMemoryStream *sms = new TMemoryStream();

sms->Write(msgData, msgSize);

Form1->IdTCPClient1->IOHandler->WriteBufferOpen();
Form1->IdTCPClient1->IOHandler->Write(sms, 0, true);
Form1->IdTCPClient1->IOHandler->WriteBufferFlush();

delete sms;
```

When I checked send data with Wireshark, I sent data that additional data and msgData to the machine.
The additional data is " 00 00 00 20 ", and it is at head of sending data.

Does IdTcpClient usually send additional data like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sending extra data because you are setting the `AWriteByteCount` parameter of `Write(TStream)` to true.  `00 00 00 20` is the stream size in network byte order.  `msgSize` is 0x00000020, aka 32.  If you do not want the stream size sent, you need to set the `AWriteByteCount` parameter to false instead:

```
Form1->IdTCPClient1->IOHandler->Write(sms, 0, false);
```

Also, you should be using `WriteBufferClose()` instead of `WriteBufferFlush()`, and do not forget to call `WriteBufferCancel()` if `Write()` raises an exception.  `WriteBufferClose()` sends the buffered data to the socket and then closes the buffer so subsequent writes are not buffered.  `WriteBufferFlush()` sends the buffered data to the socket, but does not close the buffer, thus subsequent writes will be buffered.

Also, you can simplify the overhead a little by replacing `TMemoryStream` with `TIdMemoryBufferStream`, so that you do not have to make a separate copy of your message data in memory:

```
TIdMemoryBufferStream *sms = new TIdMemoryBufferStream(msgData, msgSize);
try
{
    Form1->IdTCPClient1->IOHandler->WriteBufferOpen();
    try
    {
        Form1->IdTCPClient1->IOHandler->Write(sms, 0, true); // or false
        Form1->IdTCPClient1->IOHandler->WriteBufferClose();
    }
    catch (const Exception &)
    {
        Form1->IdTCPClient1->IOHandler->WriteBufferCancel();
        throw;
    }
}
__finally
{
    delete sms;
}
```

Alternatively, use a RAII approach:

```
class BufferIOWriting
{
private:
    TIdIOHandler *m_IO;
    bool m_Finished;

public:
    BufferIOWriting(TIdIOHandler *aIO) : m_IO(aIO), m_Finished(false)
    {
        IO->WriteBufferOpen();
    }

    ~BufferIOWriting()
    {
        if (m_Finished)
            m_IO->WriteBufferClose();
        else
            m_IO->WriteBufferCancel();
    }

    void Finished()
    {
        m_Finished = true;
    }
};

{
    std::auto_ptr<TIdMemoryBufferStream> sms(new TIdMemoryBufferStream(msgData, msgSize));
    BufferIOWriting buffer(Form1->IdTCPClient1->IOHandler);
    Form1->IdTCPClient1->IOHandler->Write(sms.get(), 0, true); // or false 
    buffer.Finished();
}
```

With that said, I would suggest just getting rid of write buffering altogether:

```
TIdMemoryBufferStream *sms = new TIdMemoryBufferStream(msgData, msgSize);
try
{
    Form1->IdTCPClient1->IOHandler->Write(sms, 0, true); // or false 
}
__finally
{
    delete sms;
}
```

Or:

```
{
    std::auto_ptr<TIdMemoryBufferStream> sms(new TIdMemoryBufferStream(msgData, msgSize));
    Form1->IdTCPClient1->IOHandler->Write(sms.get(), 0, true); // or false 
}
```

Write buffering is useful when you need to make multiple related `Write()` calls that should have their data transmitted together in as few TCP frames as possible (in other words, letting the Nagle algorithm do its job better).  For instance, if you need to `Write()` individual fields of your message.  Write buffering does not make much sense to use when making a single `Write()` call, especially of such a small size.  Let `Write(TStream)` handle its own buffering internally for you.

Comment: When I tried the 1st and 3rd answer, I sent the stream size in network byte order and msgData. What happen?

Comment: You are setting the `AWriteByteCount` parameter to **true** when calling `TIdIOHandler.Write()`.  If you do not want the stream size sent, you need to set the parameter to **false** instead.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I changed to set the parameter to false, I sent only the msgData to the machine.